# Bootstrap 4 Grid is not working properly (with example)?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, bootstrap-4

I just want to use the bootstrap 4 grid. I do not need all the other features of Bootstrap.

For some reason, the bottom line has no padding-left. Although I did not change anything about CSS instructions.

What do I have to change to make the grid display correctly?

Here is my code and a screenshot from the output:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/bootstrap-grid/bootstrap-grid.css">


  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-md-8</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
    </div>

    <!-- Columns start at 50% wide on mobile and bump up to 33.3% wide on desktop -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
    </div>

    <!-- Columns are always 50% wide, on mobile and desktop -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
    </div>
  </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: "But Bootstrap Grid is not working properly"..perhaps you should provide an example and explain why it's not working

Comment: @ZimSystem I've added an example and edited my question

Comment: The 404 error is a problem with your local environment. Also, `-xs` is no longer used in Bootstrap 4.